# Banco de Dados e Listview não funcionam

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, mvc, sqlite, listview

Estou tentando criar um aplicativo que grave dados e os exiba em um Listview, pra depois ir sofisticando o app pouco a pouco, mas na hora de salvar os dados no Banco de Dados ele não salva. No Debug ele roda tudo certinho, na última linha, como está na imagem abaixo, do nada ele retorna "false". O mais estranho é que ele parece estar buscando os dados. E o id sempre retorna "0" não entendo o porque.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então descobri também que o meu ArrayList parece não funcionar também. Toda vez que vou na parte do meu app de mostrar os dados gravados (O fragment que corresponde ao Listview) o app fecha sozinho. Usando o Debug descobri dois detalhes, um na DataSource e outro no fragment onde programo para aparecer os dados que são salvos. Normalmente eu pensaria que, como não existe nenhum dado gravado, então ele não vai funcionar. Mas acho que o app não deveria fechar sozinho, no máximo só deveria mostrar uma tela em branco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mais estranho é que eu já trabalhei com outro aplicativo usando praticamente os mesmos modelos de códigos, então não entendo porque tantos problemas.

Comment: Mostre o código do insert.

Comment: public boolean insert(String tabela, ContentValues dados) {

        boolean sucesso = true;

        try {

            sucesso = db.insert(tabela, null, dados) > 0;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            sucesso = false;
        }

        return sucesso;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Tente esse código ele coloca a operação de inserção dentro de um contexto transação de dados que é aberto com o método `beginTransaction()` é os dados são passado para o banco de dados pelo método `setTransactionSuccessful()` e o contexto de transação é fechado pelo método `endTransaction()`

```
public boolean insert(String tabela, ContentValues dados) { 
   boolean sucesso = true; 
   //Abre um contexto de transação.
   db.beginTransaction();
   try { 
         // >= pois a tabela pode estar vazia e rowID pode ser 0;
         sucesso = db.insert(tabela, null, dados) >= 0; 
         // Valida o contexto de transação.
         db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } catch (Exception e) { 
         //  Seria interessante fazer um log dessa exceção 
         //para saber se está havendo erro de comunicação com o banco de dados
         sucesso = false; 
   } finally {
     // Finaliza o contexto de transação.
     db.endTransaction();
   }
   return sucesso;
}
```

Comment: O erro persiste. Acho que vou refazer todo o MVC dando Ctrl C no outro projeto que fiz que deu certo e + Ctrl V nesse pra ver se vai funcionar, trocando só os gets e sets e os atributos da tabela. Pq não tem sentido, não estou vendo nada de errado no código. Já aconteceu de no curso eu copiar o mesmo código do mesmo projeto (uma versão do professor e a outra minha) e dar erro com os códigos iguaizinhos. Aí quando eu dei Ctrl C no projeto dele e + Ctrl V, funcionou. Até hj não entendi porquê.